# Can you use a storyboard to change the line spacing for a UILabel with a custom font?

Tags: ios

The line spacing for a UILabel can be changed within the storyboard by changing the label's text from Plain to Attributed and then change the line height multiple.

[image]

However when you do this, if the UILabel is using a custom font, when you change from plain to attributed this information is lost and the font resets to System Font size 17. However when you attempt to change the font back to the custom font, it does not appear as an option (but it does appear as an option if the label text style is plain)

[image]
(My custom font family name begins with N, it is not shown here)

Comment: Install font file on mac. Just double click on font files and it will show dialog to ask for installation font. Once it is installed on system then it would be available in storyboards/xib files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install your font on your machine. Please go through below steps to get it work.

I have following font file

```
 Montserrat-Black.otf
```

1. Double click on this font. you will get window like this.

[image]

2. Press **Install Font** button. You will get window like below.

[image]

3. Select font and click on **install checked**.
4. Quit your xcode and reopen it. Now you are all set to go. You can access font from your **storyboard** as well as from **xib** files
5. the same font appears in my xib/storyboard file.

[image]